# Blurred image HTML5 App

Tags: android, cordova

I'm new in the domain of app mobile. I want to create a little game on Android juste for testing. I don't have knowlege in JAVA so I'm making my game in HTML5/JS and I compile an .apk with phonegap.

My game work great, but my images are blurred (and my text "49 fps" ?). How can I fix ? Because when I play flappy bird or Angry bird the images are clean.

[image: my game]

The script I user to take the right size :

```
    this.screen = "drawable-ldpi";

    if(gameWidth >= 480){
        this.screen = "drawable-mdpi";
    }
    if(gameWidth >= 720){
        this.screen = "drawable-hdpi";
    }
    if(gameWidth >= 960){
        this.screen = "drawable-xhdpi";
    }
    if(gameWidth >= 1440){
        this.screen = "drawable-xxhdpi";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

They'll be blurry if they're not high enough resolution for the screen you're running on. If your images are too small, then Android will have to scale them up, and that will make them blurry.

You would ideally serve different versions of the image to different devices, depending on the screen resolution and density.

Comment: @Hotgeart well, you need to work out how much of the screen you want your image to take up, then calculate how many pixels that would require based on the screen resolution.

Comment: If i scale up my image it's to big.

Comment: @Hotgeart then you'll have to use something that can scale without looking silly. Some kind of vector graphic or ninepatch or something.